# Perl grep command for nested hash instead of using loops

Tags: perl

I have below hash structure.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'USA' => {
        'Alabama' => {
            'ISO3'    => 'ISO3:3166-2:US',
            'ISO2'    => 'ISO2:4166-23:US',
            'UNI'     => 'UNIABR-A',
            'UNDP'    => 'UNDP-ZXC-1',
            'FAOSTAT' => 'STAT20.98',
            'GAUL'    => 'UL-SD-20/40'
        },
        'Washington' => {
            'ISO3'    => 'ISO3:40-166-2:US',
            'ISO2'    => 'ISO2:30-23:US',
            'UNI'     => 'UNIISO-B',
            'UNDP'    => 'UNDP-YXC-2',
            'FAOSTAT' => 'STAT30.98.78',
            'GAUL'    => 'UL-SD-30/60'
        }
    }
};
```

What i would like to achieve is to iterate through the above hash and get the statename and country name for value inside hash "ISO2:4166-23:US". what i have tried to do is:

I can get the required output with the below code.

```
my $find = "ISO2:4166-23:US";
my $statename;

while ( my ($country, $states) = each (%$VAR1) ) {
    while (my ($states, $otherkeys) = each (%$states) ) {
        while (my ($otherkeys, $value) = each %$otherkeys) {
            $statename = $states if ($value eq $find);
        }
    }
}

print "State name for value [$find] is :: $statename \n"; ### Output : Alabama
```

Is there any way I can get -

Get the `top-level key` "USA" and `second-level key` "Alabama" if `$value` is equal to `ISO2:4166-23:US`. What i know is the value inside hash for which I need to get the output, key corresponding to my search value doesn't matter.

with one-liner grep command from above hash?

Any pointers in the right direction would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? It feels sort of like an XY-problem. There is nothing wrong with using a loop.

Comment: This would require a chain of maps and greps that would probably be less legible than using while loops. And you're not gaining anything, since grep and map are also loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are poorly named. Reusing `$states` for the state name? ouch.

```perl
my $find = "ISO2:4166-23:US";

my $found_state_name;
while ( my ($country_name, $states) = each(%$VAR1) ) {
    while (my ($state_name, $state) = each(%$states) ) {
        while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$state) ) {
            if ($value eq $find) {
                $found_state_name = $state_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it would be nice to stop searching as soon as you a result is found. We can't do that while still using `each`(cause it'll screw up later `keys`/`values`/`each` on those hashes).

```perl
my $find = "ISO2:4166-23:US";

my $found_state_name;
FIND:
for my $country_name (keys(%$VAR1)) {
    my $country = $VAR1->{$country_name};
    for my $state_name (keys(%$country)) {
        my $state = $country->{$state_name};
        for my $key (keys(%$state)) {
            if ($state->{$key} eq $find) {
                $found_state_name = $state_name;
                last FIND;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We never use `$country_name` or `$key` except to get the value.

```perl
my $find = "ISO2:4166-23:US";

my $found_state_name;
FIND:
for my $states (values(%$VAR1)) {
    for my $state_name (keys(%$states)) {
        my $state = $country->{$state_name};
        for my $value (values(%$state)) {
            if ($value eq $find) {
                $found_state_name = $state_name;
                last FIND;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you know you're looking for an `ISO2` value, this simplifies to the following:

```perl
my $find = "ISO2:4166-23:US";

my $found_state_name;
FIND:
for my $states (values(%$VAR1)) {
    for my $state_name (keys(%$states)) {
        my $state = $states->{$state_name};
        if ($state->{ISO2} eq $find) {
            $found_state_name = $state_name;
            last FIND;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You want to use `grep`, eh? Since you want a state name as a result, we need to grep a list of state names.

```perl
my @state_names = ...;

my ($found_state_name) =
   grep { ... }
      @state_names;
```

We can obtain the list of state name using

```perl
my @state_names =
   map { keys(%$_) }
      values(%$VAR1);
```

But that's not quite enough to perform the check. (For now, I'm going to assume that only the `ISO2` property needs to be checked.)

```perl
my @state_names =
   map { keys(%$_) }
      values(%$VAR1);

my ($found_state_name) =
   grep { $VAR1->{???}{$_}{ISO2} eq $find }
      @state_names;
```

There are two solutions. You can work with country-state pairs.

```perl
my @country_state_name_pairs =;
   map {
      my $country_name = $_;
      map { [ $country_name, $_ ] }
         keys(%{ $VAR1->{$country_name} )
   }
      keys(%$VAR1);

my ($found_state_name) =
   map { $_->[1] }
      grep {
         my ($country_name, $state_name) = @$_;
         $VAR1->{$country_name}{$state_name}{ISO2} eq $find
      }
         @country_state_name_pairs;
```

Or you can create a flat lists of states and search that.

```perl
my @states_with_name = 
   map { [ $_, $VAR1->{$_} ] }
      values(%$VAR1);

my ($found_state_name) =
   map { $_->[0] }
      grep { $_->[1]{ISO2} eq $find }
         @states_with_name;
```

Noting stops us from merging the two statements.

```perl
my ($found_state_name) =
   map { $_->[0] }                      # Get the state name.
      grep { $_->[1]{ISO2} eq $find }   # Filter out undesireable states.
         map { [ $_, $VAR1->{$_} ] }    # $state_name => [ $state_name, $state ]
            values(%$VAR1);             # Get the countries.
```

This last one isn't too bad!

---

Finally, there are two ways to modify each of the above to search all the fields instead of just `ISO2`). (I'm going to only the modifications to the latter of the above two solutions.)

```perl
my ($found_state_name) =
   map { $_->[0] }                      # Get the state name.
      grep {                            # Filter out undesireable states.
         grep { $_ eq $find }           # Filter out undesireable properties of the state.
            values(%{ $_->[1] })        # Get the state's property values.
      }
         map { [ $_, $VAR1->{$_} ] }    # $state_name => [ $state_name, $state ]
            values(%$VAR1);             # Get the countries.
```

or

```perl
my ($found_state_name) =
   map { $_->[0] }                        # Get the state name.
      grep { $_->[1] eq $find }           # Filter out undesireable states.
         map {                            # $state_name => multiple [ $state_name, $value ]
            my $state_name = $_;
            map { [ $state_name, $_ ] }   # value => [ $state_name, $value ]
               values(%{ $VAR1->{$_} )    # Get the state's property values.
         }
            values(%$VAR1);               # Get the countries.
```

These aren't readable. They are best avoided.

---

Finally, if you are going to perform many searches based on `ISO2`, it would be best if you organized your data in terms of `ISO2`.

```perl
my %by_iso2 = (
   'ISO2:4166-23:US' => {
      country_name => 'USA',
      state_name   => 'Alabama',
      ISO2         => 'ISO2:4166-23:US',
      ISO3         => 'ISO3:3166-2:US',
      ...
   },
   'ISO2:4166-23:US' => {
      country_name => 'USA',
      state_name   => 'Washington',
      ISO2         => 'ISO2:30-23:US',
      ISO3         => 'ISO3:40-166-2:US',
      ...
   },
   ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and providing the explanation with suggested approaches  and correcting the mistakes in approach taken by me.

Answer (score 1):

No. Hashes are one-directional, so you have to loop over all the values to find one you are searching for.

It sounds like what you really want is some sort of database and that a hash is the wrong tool for your job.

You can build your hash the other way around, using the `ISO2` as the key, e.g.

```
$VAR1 = { 
    "ISO2:4166-23:US" => { Country => 'USA', State => 'Alabama' },
    "ISO2:4166-23:US" => { Country => 'USA', State => 'Washington' }
}
```

If you are planning to do these lookups a lot, it might be worth the while. Doing that can be automated too. Using a similar loop to build a new hash to use as lookup.

Speed-wise, there is nothing wrong with looping over all the hash keys. The difference between direct lookup and looping will be negligible, unless you have a truly huge hash.